# dynamically specify group class when group count is zero without using join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Okay, so I got a dataset as simple as:

```
id  |  condition
INT |  boolean
```

I want to group by ID and get a count of each condition, including zeros.

```
id  |  condition  |  count
1   |    TRUE     |    17
1   |    FALSE    |    2
2   |    TRUE     |    0
2   |    FALSE    |    15
3   |    TRUE     |    3
3   |    FALSE    |    0
... |     ...     |   ...
```

The thing is, there is a large number of ids, and a large number of them with only TRUE or only FALSE conditions.

I would like to account for 0 counts on my aggregated table.

So my question is, can I do this in Amazon Redshift, without joining with another table? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate data conditionally and unpivot the result

```
select t.id, c.condition, c.count
from (
   select id, count(case when condition then condition end) ct, 
      count(case when not condition then condition end) cf
   from tbl
   group by id
) t
cross join lateral (
   values( true, coalesce(ct,0)), (false, coalesce(cf,0))
) c(condition, count)
```

The above query uses LATERAL to unpivot data. Alternatively you can use arrays. Both versoins engage no other tables.

```
select t.id, unnest(array[true, false]) condition, unnest(array[ct,cf]) count
from (
   select id, count(case when condition then condition  end) ct, 
     count(case when not condition then condition  end) cf
   from tbl
   group by id) t
order by t.id, condition desc
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=006a13271fea0dd8a76a7c2c60595200)

Comment: thx - but I was wondering if I could do that without a join command

Comment: @epattaro,   see the edited answer.

Comment: Thx! Sorry, failed to mention I am doing this in redshift, which runs on postgresql 8.0.2

Neither this solutions work (unfortunately)

Comment: @epattaro,  UNION of 2 conditional aggregation queries should work on most DBMSes

Answer (score 0):

Just see if the below query can solve your problem.

```
select id,sum(t) as t, sum(f) as f 
from (select id,case when condition='t' then count(id) else 0 end as t,
case when condition='f' then count(id) else 0 end as f
from tbl
group by id,condition) t
group by id
order by id
```

can be validated on [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d0595c1891cf77f944606ce00f3ee172)

Comment: Thats close; I am trying to get the condition in a single output column (see example)